Interpreting logistic regression coefficients in "percentage increase/decrease"
I understand that from logistic regression, (let's say with two predictors)
$$\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$$
and that when $x_1$ is binary, this can be interpreted as below
$e^{\hat\beta_1} = \frac{odds(p|x_1 = 1)}{odds(p|x_1 = 0)}$
I was reading a paper that utilized logistic linear regression, and the result looks like this.
$$\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = -1.86-0.15\times x_1 + 0.33\times x_2$$
$x_1$ is a continuous variable, while $x_2$ is binary.
As far as I understand, below is how the authors interpret the results.

A one-unit increase in the $x_1$ about the mean is associated with a 13-percent decrease in the probability $p$.
$x_2 = 1$ corresponds to a 34-percent increase in $p$ relative to $x_2 = 0$

I can interpret the coefficients in terms of the odds ratio, but when discussing the percentage increase/decrease in p, how was this number derived?
I've been struggling to understand for hours, so I could really use some help! Thank you in advance.
Also, for more information about the paper, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2657467.

This is an example of why many experienced analysts don't like percents.
What the authors have done is converted the logistic regression predictions to probability values, and then reported the percentage difference in the probability from a particular baseline value. To use the equation this way you need also to have the mean value of $x_1$ in this data set, which is 2.53 according to its Table 1. I've also taken the liberty to add in the extra digit shown in that Table for each of the coefficients. In R you can then use the plogis() function to convert from log-odds to probability.
The probability of the binary outcome (low birth weight in this study) in reference conditions ($x_1$ at its mean, $x_2=0$) is
plogis(-1.864-0.149*2.53)
# [1] 0.09613123

The probability of the outcome when $x_1$ is increased by 1 unit from the mean, to a value of 3.53 is
plogis(-1.864-0.149*3.53)
# [1] 0.08394074

The "percentage change" in the probability of the outcome associated with the 1-unit increase in $x_1$ is
100*(0.08394074-0.09613123)/0.09613123
# [1] -12.68109

Similarly, at the mean value of $x_1$, the outcome probability for changing $x_2$ to a value of 1 is
plogis(-1.864-0.149*2.53+0.333)
# [1] 0.1292091

for a "percentage change" from the reference condition of
100*(0.1292091-0.09613123)/0.09613123
# [1] 34.40908

Numerically, these results agree with the statements by the authors in the text that you quote.
The statements are potentially misleading in at least three ways.
First, do you really care about the "percentage change" of the probability values. Aren't the actual differences in predicted probabilities more useful?
Second, the "percentage change" values depend on the choice of reference condition. The calculations above used $x_1$ at its mean, $x_2=0$ as the reference, but if you chose a different reference condition the "percentage change" values would be different. That's particularly the case as you have to transform here from the log-odds scale of the linear predictor to the probability scale.
Third, the point estimates of these "percentage change" values ought at least to be accompanied by estimates in the associated errors. For example, how reliable is the estimate of a "13-percent decrease in the probability of being born of low birth weight" that's associated with a 1-unit increase in the income-to-needs ratio?
Finally, this model ("Model 1" in the paper) assumes a strict linear association between the log-odds of the outcome and the income-to-needs ratio, while omitting several outcome-associated predictors that are included in other models. Strict linear associations are the exception rather than the rule; a flexible fit with a spline might have documented that. Omitting any outcome-associated predictor from a logistic regression model leads to bias in coefficient estimates of the included predictors. See this page for a nice explanation.
Unfortunately, one of the extended models (Model 3) included predictors for "missing data." That's generally unreliable; it's better to do multiple imputation of missing data instead. See Stef van Buuren's Flexible Imputation of Missing Data, in particular Section 1.3.7 on this "indicator method" for handling missing values.

Ohh now it finally makes sense why they would say increase "about the mean"! Thank you so much for taking the time and looking into the paper.
I completely agree with you that this percentage comparison is absurd, especially when we are already looking at probability values. I'll also look into the pages you linked. You really saved my day :)

I was reading through following your explanation, and I'm kind of confused with the model 3 in Table 2.
In R, I calculated the reference point
`ref <- plogis(-1.378-0.0882.36+0.4390.47+0.1990.42-0.1110.316+0.019*12.06)
low = 0, income-to-needs ratio = 2.36(mean), maternal age = 0`
Then, for a unit increase in income-to-needs ratio, i should get
income <- plogis(-1.378-0.088*3.36+0.439*0.47+0.199*0.42-0.111*0.316+0.019*12.06)
Then if I compare them by percentage ((income - ref)/ref), I don't get 6 percent increase(page 8 of the article) as the authors say why would that be?

I think that the authors used reference levels of all the categorical predictors (including female child, first-born child, African American, along with low birth weidht and maternal age <18) rather than the mean values as you did for 3 of those. Also, the coefficient for income-to-needs ratio is $0.088$, not $-0.088$ as in your code. I then get the "6 percent" increase for a 1-unit increase in income-to-needs, although I get a 36% "decline" associated with low-birth-weight birth rather than their 34%.
